How do I fix this problem in google sites?
I tried making an embed for https://www.coolmathgames.com/sites/default/files/public_games/49389/
But all it showed me was a white screen
I also tried
https://www.coolmathgames.com/0-ovo/play
But it said “Can’t embed due to provider site permissions. URL will display as a text link” which is a problem because the original website is blocked on our school devices
